Preprocessor #warning does not work anymore in Xcode 16?
I have check like below to make an error or a warning on Macos during compilation.
SomeHeader.hpp

#if SOME_CONDITION
    #warning This is a warning.
#endif

But the line with #warning has started to fail with an error on Xcode 16. Has something changed in the Clang compiler?
